# How to push updates to IOS device through TCP/IP socket from server?

Tags: java, ios, sockets, tcp, chat

We need to have a messaging feature in our app(Like that in Facebook IOS app to tell you there is new story in news feed and the chatting system). Bearing in mind that Apple's push notification is seemingly not going to be an option since the payload is large and frequency of transaction might potentially be huge we have been seeking for way to implement this ourselves. Since polling our database right from IOS devices is also not a very good idea we decided to make a TCP server implemented in Java. Since we are really inexperienced programmers(College students actually) I have questions to ask:

How does our Java program know if there is any updates occurred in our database? Do we have to poll database from inside of the Java code? Because by the time those updates occur the socket code is already running(It's obviously an infinite loop) how do we let it know from outside the program something new has happened? Java or PHP is preferable when it comes to TCP socket?

My idea now is to poll database using Java when an client is connected to the socket. When there is update Java writes it to socket.

Is this the right way? Or you guys have a better idea?

Please be specific due to our novice station.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution will only work if the app is actually running. (And perhaps, crippled, if the user let's it run in the background - see Apple's multitasking in iOS documentation for details). When running in the background, you won't be able to bring up a UI for the user to see, and you won't be able to provide a message or badge in the built in iOS message center. It will also be a lot of work to implement.

A common approach is to use Apple push notifications, and let the payload be an identifier, which your app can use to retrieve the actual (larger) payload from your API. Using Apple push notifications has a lot of benefits, such as being tightly integrated in the OS.

As for your actual question: One solution is to poll the DB from the Java code. But it really depends on where the actual data gets generated from. Is it some system you can hook into ? In that case it would be more efficient to have the system call out to you when something changes, your Java code can then generate the notification.

Comment: When user is in the background then shif to Apple's notification. My trepidation to your proposal is that would that be too slow for the chatting feature? The app needs to wait for Push notification and then query database. Does this provide the real time effect that we see in Facebook app? And Apple doc says that the delivery of push notification is not guaranteed, should this also be concern when it comes to real time uese experience?